# How to store and retrieve image from a Hive table

Tags: image, hadoop, hive

I want to store image in hive table and then retrieve the image to display it on the dashboard. Can i do it without using any Java coding? I have successfully created hive table and loaded the image file in it in a column with a binary datatype but the image file in HDFS is like this

> �����JFIF��`�`������Exif��MM�*�����������>�������F(��������i�������N�������`������`����������z���`����UNICODE��C�R�E�A�T�O�R�:� �g�d�-�j�p�e�g� �v�1�.�0� �(�u�s�i�n�g� �I�J�G� �J�P�E�G� �v�6�2�)�,� �q�u�a�l�i�t�y� �=� �9�0�
>   ���C�..........

Can any one kindly help me how to retrieve the image from Hive table.

Comment: please describe in more detail what it is you are trying to do exactly, this is really vague.
Are doing doing a cat from hdfs? or trying to view binary data via hue? If the latter is the case: "no" is the answer. PS: why go with hive for image storage? do you want to do mass processing on it? or use it as an image database to display in (web) applications? because then you will be in for a nasty experience and hive is NOT the usecase for you.

Comment: what you are seeing their is a try to interprete the binary data as unicode, which for obvious reasons won't work. You need some logic which builds a picture from the binary data.

Comment: yes it is cat from HDFS. Yes i want to store image and display it on dashboard. As i am using Oracle Big Data Discovery for building dashboards and it only supports hive tables in it as far as i know thats why i am using hive table.

Comment: how have you stored images in the hive?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. You say that you have already stored it in a Table using binary Data Type. Can you share the details of how you did it? The question that is open to answer is how to you visualize it in a dashboard?

Hive exposes a Hive Server connection using which you will be able to query the hive table from your webpage. Essentially it is a Select * statement and then what you do with the data is up to you.

Comment: Create table image(picture binary); Now to load image in it i simply used the load data statement as: load data local inpath 'x/y/image.jpg' into table image; Thats how i did it. I just want to display the image of the person stored in the table.

Comment: Looks like you uploaded to 1 picture to the table Daniyal. Did you do a `select count(*) from image`. These tables have delimiters as `\n` and if there is a ascii `013` in the data you will read multiple lines in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are loading data using `load data inpath`but your hive expects the data being provided in Binary format. This is issue of hive not understanding the data. Viewing JPEG file from dashboard hive is assuming that .jpeg file is binary format and decoding the data. I would recommend using some method (java or other) to convert the .jpeg file to binary format before using your `load data inpath` command.